# Site.login method invalid password issue

Tags: apex, community, security, login

I have to develop custom login page in a LWR community.

I configured maximum wrong login attempts number in the Customer Profile, but I've recently found that `Site.login` does not increase number of invalid login attempts. So the user is never locked, which certainly leaves my community vulnerable to password enumeration attacks.

Could you please recommend how I can track invalid login attempts and lock user?